# Spark and AWS S3 Connection Error: Not able to read file from S3 location through spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

In below spark-shell I am trying to connect to S3 and load file to create dataframe:

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "")
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "")
scala> val weekly = 
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load("s3://usr_bucket/data/file.csv")
scala> print(weekly)
scala> weekly.show()
```

Error msg:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/Jets3tFileSystemStore.initialize(Ljava/net/URI;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V @43: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'org/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'org/jets3t/service/security/ProviderCredentials'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @43
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/Jets3tFileSystemStore', 'java/net/URI', 'org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration', 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/S3Credentials', 'org/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/Jets3tFileSystemStore', uninitialized 37, uninitialized 37, 'org/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2c b500 02bb 0003 59b7 0004 4e2d 2b2c
    0000010: b600 05bb 0006 592d b600 072d b600 08b7
    0000020: 0009 3a04 2abb 000a 5919 04b7 000b b500
    0000030: 0ca7 0023 3a04 1904 b600 0ec1 000f 9900
    0000040: 0c19 04b6 000e c000 0fbf bb00 1059 1904
    0000050: b700 11bf 2abb 0012 592b b600 13b7 0014
    0000060: b500 152a 2c12 1611 1000 b600 17b5 0018
    0000070: b1
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [19, 49] => handler: 52
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@52,{Object[#194],Object[#195],Object[#196],Object[#197]},{Object[#198]})
    append_frame(@74,Object[#198])
    chop_frame(@84,1)

        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.createDefaultStore(S3FileSystem.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.initialize(S3FileSystem.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2816)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2853)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2835)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1307)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1302)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1342)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1341)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine$lzycompute(CsvRelation.scala:269)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine(CsvRelation.scala:265)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.inferSchema(CsvRelation.scala:242)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.<init>(CsvRelation.scala:74)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:171)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
        at <init>(<console>:58)
        at .<init>(<console>:62)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `s3a` filesystem

```
load("s3a://usr_bucket/data/file.csv")
```

Comment: I have tried with s3a://, s3n:// and s3://.  I am able to access s3 location from AWS CLI : aws s3 cp s3://usr_bucket/data/file.csv /usr/local/file.csv

Comment: Yes, but Spark prefers using `s3a`, as per the Hadoop framework. https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 And your properties set it as so. `fs.s3a.access...` The AWS CLI does not have the concept of `s3a` or `s3n`

Comment: hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")... add this along with access_key n scret_key...things will work...it's working for me