# Spark streaming connection to S3 gives Forbidden error

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I'm running a Spark streaming app from my local to read from an S3 bucket.

I'm using the Hadoop-AWS jar to set S3 authentication parameters - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authenticating_with_S3

This is the error message 'Forbidden':

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - Error Message: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: #####, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - HTTP Status Code: 403
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - AWS Error Code: null
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - Error Type: Client
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - Request ID: #####
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem printAmazonServiceException - Class Name: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception
```

Code to read from bucket:

```
val sc: SparkContext = createSparkContext(scName)
val hadoopConf=sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(time))
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("s3a://foldername/subfolder/")
lines.print()
```

I have set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` variables on my terminal but it still gives me 'Forbidden'.

I am able to access S3 from the terminal though (using the AWS profile) so I'm not sure why it doesn't work when I go through Spark. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You need to export those variables to all executors, not just your local machine

Comment: Are you located in any embargoed countries?

Comment: @cricket_007 how do I do that? If I set those variables in hadoopConf isn't that enough?

Comment: @MobinRanjbar no I'm not

Comment: `"fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"` only sets **the filesystem**. You also need to set the keys. See code here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49230086/2308683 Also see https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/spark_s3.html#spark_s3_credentials  Search for "Specify the credentials at run time"

Comment: I tried setting the keys directly in the code and by exporting the AWS environment variables (given above). Both still give me 'Forbidden'. But when I use those keys from the terminal to access that S3 bucket, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obfuscate the keys away from the code in plain-text.

You can add a `core-site.xml` file to the classpath with the keys

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>...</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>...</value>
</property>
```

Or if you don't care about putting the keys directly in the code,

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "...")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "...")
```

The recommended way is to [use a Java jceks credential file](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/spark_s3.html#spark_s3_credentials)

Comment: I tried putting the keys directly in the code and that gives the same Forbidden error.

Comment: It might be a problem that Spark hasn't done a proper release saying that Hadoop 3 is supported now. Or if you aren't using it... This is the only ways I know of to set the keys. So there is some other error going on because `AWS Error Code: null` shouldn't be happening

Comment: Nothing related to hadoop 3 there.This is more one of config, hampered by the fact that nobody dares print out useful diagnostics information

Comment: @Steve The link in the question was to Hadoop 3 docs (although I understand that page hasn't changed much)